# Removing the place holder when I make the form disable

Tags: angular

I have a input tag in the form which contains placeholder, at some point I'm disabling(read-only) the form with out entering any value in that input field, how to disable or remove that place holder when I turn the form to read-only.

I expect the place holder need to be gone when I didn't enter any data in that input field and make the form read-only

Comment: it would be great if you provide us your code so we can give you better answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use placeholder as angular attribute using square brackets around html attribute and use template reference variable to check whether input is disabled or not
something like this,

```
<input type="text" #inputField disabled [placeholder]="inputField.disabled? '': 'User Name'" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your using a variable `readOnly` to change the disabled(read-only) status of your input from your ts file.

In your HTML, write

```
<input
    [placeholder]="readOnly ? '': 'Name'"
    [readOnly]="readOnly"
    // ... other attributes
/>
```